# Suitble BaaS for a chat app

Tags: backend, mbaas

For a beginner who wants to build a simple chat app, and doesn't want to waste time learning how to develop a backend and secure it, what could be the best BaaS?

When I was googling I came across several services such as 
**Firebase**, and I liked it, it's very easy to use and well documented, but the sad part is that the user must be active to receive messages it doesn't support push notifications. And most of the others (like Buddy) is very costly.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: parse shutting down left a big hole.  The one I've been looking at is backand www.backand.com  they don't have push notifications yet but it says they are coming.  It's rather new so development is ongoing.

Comment: you might also want to look into pubnub or socket.io

Answer (score 1):

It's all entirely done by systems like sendbird, or now there's getstream.io made by the Algolia people.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Built.io Backend](https://www.built.io/products/backend/overview). It provides push notification and real-time micro services. Using these, you can create a solution for your requirement.

Comment: is built.io dead?